# How to create mysql user from unix user by using shadow hash

Tags: mysql, passwords, chef-infra

Is there a way to create a Mysql user from existing unix user without asking plain password.
Instead of it by using shadow hash.

It would be great if you know how to do it with chef, but it also very helpful if you tell me how to do it directly by mysql command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way and it is by far not Chef's "fault".

MySQL uses an own `PASSWORD()` method to hash passwords. There is AFAIK no support for the libcrypt style hashed passwords. More information can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html), but I didn't find anything related to other hashing methods.